# Click on thumbnail to play youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm working on mobile device (iOS) and I want to click on a thumbnail to launch a youtube video. On iOS device the video appears in fullscreen.

I'm using iframe but i want to use only image:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="120" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'?hd=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"/>
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="120" height="100"  
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'?hd=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0" 
frameborder="0"/>
```

The required jQuery:

```
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
      height: '200',
      width: '200',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
  event.target.playVideo();
    $("#play").on('click', function() {
      player.playVideo();
    });
    $("#pause").on('click', function() {
      player.stopVideo();
    });
}
```

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/218/

As you can see, it is very important you add the parameter: `&enablejsapi=1` to you `src`.

Also, the passing of the `video id` through the initialisation of your player didn't work correctly.

**What you want to achieve**

What you want to achieve is to start the video by clicking an image (at least if I understand correctly).
As you can see in the `JsFiddle`, I now created a `play` button which starts the video. You can now substitute an image or anything else you want to initialise the video.

I hope this helps you out!

Good luck!

Comment: I think that's because jsfiddle is down :(

Comment: @adibouf: jsfiddle is up again. Try again ;)

Comment: can you check my new question please :s

Answer (score 0):

The URLs of the thumbnails are predictable:

> http://img.youtube.com/vi/[id]/0.jpg
>
> http://img.youtube.com/vi/[id]/1.jpg
>
> http://img.youtube.com/vi/[id]/2.jpg
>
> http://img.youtube.com/vi/[id]/3.jpg

See this answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/318557

Comment: Thanks , i know that ! I just want to have an examples like : I click on an image (thumbnail or not) and launch my youtube video on my iOS device.